# How to handle concurrency clash in ASP.Net MVC using post-redirect-get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, concurrency, post-redirect-get

I use a post-redirect-get (PRG) pattern to save an entity in ASP.Net MVC 2. The controller methods are 'Save' (inserts or updates database) and 'Edit' (retrieves user input). In 'Save', I do modification check before saving by checking a 'version' column of the entity. If someone else has modified the entity, the 'version' column will not match and I will send error message to the user.

To maintain error messages, I use ModelState.Merge in 'Edit' method. The problem with this mechanism is that the user input is maintained and the user doesn't see the modification made by the other user. I avoid this problem by clearing ModelState before adding the concurrency clash message.

But I feel this solution is not optimal. How would you handle concurrency clash in ASP.Net MVC?

Here is the Edit method:

```
    Public Function Edit() As ActionResult
        Dim theevent As AEvents

        If TempData("ModelState") IsNot Nothing And Not ModelState.Equals(TempData("ModelState")) Then
            ModelState.Merge(CType(TempData("ModelState"), ModelStateDictionary))
        End If

        If RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("id") Then
            theevent = NHibGet.EventWithPricingsByCode(RouteData.Values("id"))
        Else
            theevent = New AEvents
        End If

        Dim InputTemplate As New EventEdit With {.EventDate = theevent.EventDate, .EventName = theevent.EventName, .IsActive = theevent.IsActive}
        If theevent.Template IsNot Nothing Then
            InputTemplate.TemplateID = theevent.Template.ID
        End If

        Dim templates As IList(Of SeatTemplates) = NHibGet.TemplatesActive
        ViewData("templates") = templates

        ViewData("eventcode") = theevent.Code
        ViewData("editversion") = theevent.Version

        Return View(InputTemplate)
    End Function
```

And the code for 'Save' is like this:

```
    Public Function Save(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal UserData As EventEdit, ByVal EditVersion As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim theevent As AEvents
        If id = 0 Then
            theevent = New AEvents
        Else
            theevent = NHibGet.EventByCode(id)
        End If

        If theevent.Version <> EditVersion Then
            ModelState.Clear()
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The event is modified by someone else")
            Return RedirectToAction("Edit", New With {.id = id})
        End If

        If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
            TempData("ModelState") = ModelState
            Return RedirectToAction("Edit", New With {.id = id})
        End If

        theevent.EventDate = UserData.EventDate
        theevent.EventName = UserData.EventName
        theevent.IsActive = UserData.IsActive
        theevent.Template = MvcApplication.CurrentSession.Load(Of SeatTemplates)(UserData.TemplateID)

        Using trans As NHibernate.ITransaction = MvcApplication.CurrentSession.BeginTransaction
            MvcApplication.CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(theevent)

            Try
                trans.Commit()
            Catch ex As NHibernate.ADOException
                trans.Rollback()
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Using

        Return RedirectToAction("Edit", New With {.id = theevent.Code})
    End Function
```

Comment: Feels like this isn't at all ASP.NET MVC specific. Either you need to lock items for editing, or you need to allow merging items when saving, or you need to overwrite items when saving. Sounds like the merge option is what you want. Perhaps you could present the current user's now-obsolete edits in a read-only format when attempting to save an old version to allow the current user to manually merge each field?

Comment: I'd say that my question is MVC specific because if someone would give example in PHP, it may not be translatable to MVC. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am always in such a case instructs the user to refresh the page. It also gives him the opportunity to review fields values ​​that entered.